# Свободные альтернативы UPX для сжатия исполняемых файлов

Tags: поиск-программ, сжатие, upx, исполняемый-файл

Ищу свободные альтернативы к `UPX` (`Ultimate Packer for eXecutables`).

Причины:

1. Часть кода UPX защищена авторскими правами.
2. UPX добавляет информацию об авторских правах создателей в сжатые исполняемые файлы и запрещает её удалять.

Есть ли какие-нибудь свободные альтернативы, которые, как и UPX, обеспечивают возможность запуска сжатого исполняемого файла без распаковки?

Может быть, есть способ упаковать сжатый в другой программе файл в новый исполняемый?

Comment: На какую операционную систему?

Comment: @eri ну меня интересует больше линукс, потому что я только на нём и сижу. И вообще я за линукс. Но если есть что сказать про виндовс, то, думаю, для кого-то это тоже будет полезно.

Comment: У upx вижу сигнатуру, но не вижу копирайты в готовом файле.

Comment: @eri там есть как минимум следующие фрагменты:
1. 4 раза "UPX!"
2. "PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE failed"
3. "Info: This file is packed with the UPX executable packer http://upx.sf.net "
3. "Id: UPX 3.** Copyright (C) 1996-20** the UPX Team. All Rights Reserved. "
(звёздочками заменены данные, разные в разных версиях)
Второй пункт, наверное, используется для вывода ошибок, но по мне он тоже лишний ;)

Comment: а, нашел. похоже 1 и 2 пункт взаимоисключающие.

Comment: @eri не понял, что значит, что 1 и 2 пункты взаимоисключающие?

Comment: пункты вопроса. без следов работют только платные упаковщики. а из бесплатных наверное только upx распаковывает на лету.

Comment: я пытался сделать шифровальщик эльфов, но не нашел способа чтоб он запускался без создания файла или виртуального файла.

Comment: @eri я тут подумал: может быть, можно это как-то с помощью `AppImage` сделать? Это же по сути архив, то есть аналог виндовсовскому .exe-шнику.

Comment: по типу appimage есть gzexe. appimage разпаковывается во временную папку и оттуда запускается

Comment: @eri я посмотрел информацию по gzexe: но он не связан с AppImage. Однако он сжимает исполняемый файл и преобразует его в .sh-скрипт, так что это можно считать частичным решением. Получается исполняемый файл, но только не бинарный.

Comment: Я пробовал преобразовать этот файл в бинарный с помощью `shc`, но ничего не получилось. Видимо, `shc` не умеет обращаться со специальными символами, которые оказываются в выходном файле команды `gzexe`.

Comment: не связан, но по типу.

Comment: для gzexe важно смещение бинарных данных. shc это смещение смещает

Comment: А не проще паковать дисковый раздел прямо средствами ОС? Мне казалось в том числе и поэтому упаковщики исполняемых файлов перестали быть актуальными. Проще раздел весь паковать, ну или можно даже папки, как в Винде.

Comment: @CrazyElf был бы признателен, если бы вы показали пример :)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, я бы скажем `*.iso *.isz` взял) можно даже свою ОС туда докинуть и запускать baremetal. но разумеется я не он, скорее всего имелось ввиду нечто другое :3 ну или... не совсем такое - виртуалки с контейнерами думаю как раз то что надо

Comment: а всёже какая цель этой сжималки? зачем паковать блендер?

Comment: @eri ну блендер я пакую для проверки работоспособности решения. А так я просто хочу достичь максимального уменьшения размера своего исполняемого файла.

Comment: В оперативке он будет занимать свой изначальный размер, а размер дисков большинства компьютеров позволяет не паковать его. я вот пакую (и ещё шифрую) для предотвращения отладки и извлечения строк. Зачем делать исполняемый файл меньше?

Comment: @eri ну, во-первых, из спортивного интереса, а во-вторых, передача по сети будет быстрее. Ну я согласен, что это не что-то супер-важное, но приятно.

Comment: по сети передавать лучше в установщике или в пакета. там и сжатие же есть

Answer (score 0):

Для Виндовс нашел список упаковщиков PE: http://pect.atspace.com/

- ASPACK
- BAMBAM
- CRUNCH
- EXE32PACK
- EXPRESSOR
- EZIP
- FSG
- JDPACK
- MEW10
- MEW11 SE
- NEOLITE
- NsPACK
- PACKLITE
- PACKMAN
- PCSHRINKER
- PECOMPACT
- PEDIMINISHER
- PEPACK
- PEQUAKE
- PETITE
- PEX
- PKLITE32
- POLYENE
- SHRINKER32
- TELOCK
- THUNDERBOLT
- UPACK
- UPX
- WWPACK32

Answer (score 0):

Для Линукса можно упаковать готовый экзешник таким образом:

packed.c

```cpp
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <lzma.h>

#include "bin.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    int fd = memfd_create(argv[0], 0);
    lzma_stream strm = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
    lzma_filter filters[LZMA_FILTERS_MAX + 1];
    filters[0].id = LZMA_FILTER_LZMA2;
    static lzma_options_lzma opt_lzma;
    filters[0].options = &opt_lzma;
    lzma_lzma_preset(&opt_lzma, LZMA_PRESET_DEFAULT);
    filters[1].id = LZMA_VLI_UNKNOWN;
    lzma_ret ret = lzma_raw_decoder(&strm, filters);
    if (ret != LZMA_OK)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    uint8_t *inbuf;
    uint8_t outbuf[BUFSIZ];
    strm.next_in = NULL;
    strm.avail_in = BUFSIZ;
    strm.next_out = outbuf;
    strm.avail_out = sizeof(outbuf);
    lzma_action action = LZMA_RUN;
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < bin_len; i += BUFSIZ) {
        strm.next_in = &(bin[i]);
        strm.avail_in = BUFSIZ;
        if (i + BUFSIZ > bin_len) {
            action = LZMA_FINISH;
            strm.avail_in = bin_len - i;
        }
        do {
            strm.next_out = outbuf;
            strm.avail_out = sizeof(outbuf);
            ret = lzma_code(&strm, action);
            if ((ret != LZMA_OK) && (ret != LZMA_STREAM_END))
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            else
                write(fd, outbuf, (BUFSIZ - strm.avail_out));
        } while (strm.avail_out == 0);
    }
    lzma_end(&strm);
    fchmod(fd, S_IRWXU);
    return fexecve(fd, argv, envp);
}
```

build.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Ошибка: Не хватает аргумента командной строки."
    exit 1
fi

IN=$1
OUT=$(basename "$1")"_compressed"

echo -e "#include <sys/types.h>\n\nconst unsigned char bin[] = {" > bin.h
cat $IN | lzma -9 --format=raw | xxd -i >> bin.h
echo -e "};\n\nconst ssize_t bin_len = sizeof(bin) / sizeof(bin[0]);" >> bin.h

gcc ./packed.c -Os -flto -s -Wl,-s -Wl,--gc-sections -o $OUT -llzma
strip -s $OUT
```

Использование:

```
# Установка необходимых пакетов
apt install gcc liblzma-dev xxd xz-utils binutils
# Сборка сжатого исполняемого файла (например, /usr/bin/nano)
./build.sh /usr/bin/nano
# Запуск собранного файла
./nano_compressed
```

Исполнимый файл будет распакован в память. Имя файлу присвоено не будет и поэтому возможны проблемы с этим связанные. Замените тогда `memfd_creat` на `tmpfile` или `creat`.

Comment: Кажется, что у `xxd` нет опции `-n`. А без неё файл `bin.h` состоит просто из последовательности юникод-символов. И переменной `bin_len`, например, не обнаруживается.

Comment: Я добавил вручную в файл объявление массива `bin` и `bin_len`. Моя маленькая программа весом 126 килобайт ужалась до 47 и работает, однако я попробовал протестировать этот код на `/bin/blender` и `/bin/texmaker` - и ни та, ни другая не запустились. Хотя размер у обеих прилично сжался.

Comment: К слову, я проверил, насколько хорошо `upx` сжимает `blender`: всего на 140 килобайт лучше, чем ваш код. И это на максимальных настройках. Надо всё-таки понять, почему сжатый вашим кодом файл не запускается.

Comment: (Файл блендера весит 86.4 мегабайта. Ваш код ужал его в 21.8 МБ, UPX - в 21.7 МБ)

Comment: Ну я же говорил, что сработает с простыми программами. Upx сжимает станицы, оставляя линковку . а тут контейнер с экзешником. Смотрите через команду strace какой вызов не сработал и где оно упало.

Comment: А почему наивное сжатие не должно работать? Если сжатие и разжатие работают правильно, то в итоге должен получиться тот же файл, что был сжат.

Comment: Во первых файл виртуальный и заделан без параметров больших страниц памяти. Его может рвёт где-то.

Comment: Его программа может пытаться открыть через argv[0] и пытаться считать данные, но попадает на сжатый файл. Возможна линковка на самого себя.

Comment: Куча чего может быть. Попробуй отладить это. Попробуй поменять файл на реальный вместо memfd. Доходит ли до execve? На каком вызове крашится?

Comment: ну я глянул. падает после приерно 1300 операции  `write(3, ...` значит в рам файл записалось примерно 8-10 мегабайт.

Comment: А нельзя никак присвоить файлу имя? Может быть, это всё исправит.

Comment: Имя то у него есть, но не понятно как сработает open по нему) используй что-то из стандартного creat , open, tmpfile чтоб создать файл на диске. Но учти что его надо будет удалить после запуска программы

Comment: 1) Вы же в ответе написали, что "Имя файлу присвоено не будет", а сейчас говорите, что имя есть. 2) Я попробовал создать временный файл, но блендер запустить так и не удалось. Программа вылетает на 201-ой итерации цикла for.

Comment: оно как бы и есть (параметр в функции) но его нет в файловой системе и в каталогах

Comment: 2) тут дело в размере файла. 201 операция это сколько мегабайт примерно? если временный не получается - попробуйте создать обычный. если вылетает в цикле - дело не в имени, а в записи такого размера